# Theoretical issue about Ajax with custom php MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm building my first AJAX website where I implemented a custom MVC.

Basicly I'm sending with AJAX (via jQuery) the section to a big PHP switch which responds the part of the HTML/PHP page which is injected to the index page through AJAX.

My issue comes when, for instance, the response has a form wich I want to get with AJAX.

If I put my script to retrieve this form in my JavaScript file it does'nt work... but when I put my script in the same page that the html response it works and I'm thinking thats not a properly way to code... Am I wrong?

Is there anyway to gather all the JavaScript code in only one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have PHP code in your JS file? If so, that is the problem, the JS file does not get parsed by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to assign an event handler to your form. For example you might want to assign an event handler that handles the submit event of your form.

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
   $.post("sendFromDataHere.php", $(this).serialize());
});
```

Now, you have two scenarios.

1. You put this script in your main js file.
2. You put this script together with the returned html.

2 works, 1 does not. This is because in scenario 1, #myForm does not exist in the DOM when the script is executed. 2 works because it is loaded as #myForm is inserted into the DOM, thus the event handler can be assigned.

So what to do? 2 most certainly is bad practice. To assign handlers to elements that are inserted into the DOM sometime in the future you can use jQuery's functions [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). If you use the latest version of jQuery (>= v1.7) you should take a look at the recently added [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). As I understand it, it is now supposed to be used instead of .bind(), .live() and .delegate().

Here is how the script would look like using .do().

```
$("body").on("submit", "#myForm", function() {
   $.post("sendFromDataHere.php", $(this).serialize());
});
```

A good practice would be to replace the "body" selector with the selector of the container you are inserting the html into.

The following is quoted form the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation.

> "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design..."

Using this way of assigning event handlers to your form, you should be able to put your scripts in your main js file.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your very complete answer! I'll try that

Comment: Actually it's working fine for : $("#content").on("submit", "#amyform", function() {// code} but when I'm doing :  $("#myDiv").on("click", function(){//code} it's the same problem as before... It work when the script is put with the HTML returned but not in my js file... Do you have any idea why it's working for a submit but not for a click event...

Comment: Cool! $("#content").on() should work fine if the "content" container always is present in the DOM.